# How to hide/show layout in response to scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, show-hide

So here is my activity's layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
    <include
        layout="@layout/signs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:clipToPadding="false">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `signs` include:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:elevation="4dp">


    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/navi_door"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/door_24"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I scroll a list of items of `RecyclerView` the signs layout stays at it's place, of course. And that's why my question is how to make this layout also be scrolled then RecyclerView's list is scrolled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `RecyclerView` does not support adding Header/Footer like ListView you can achieve this like following :

```
private class ViewType {
        public static final int Signs = 1;
        public static final int Normal = 2;
}
```

Then override `getItemViewType`:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if(items.get(position).isHeader)
        return ViewType.Signs;
    else
        return ViewType.Normal;

}
```

And finally override `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View rowView;

    switch (i)
    {       
        case ViewType.Signs:
            rowView=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.signs, viewGroup, false);
            break;

        default:
            rowView=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.normal, viewGroup, false);
            break;
    }
    return new ViewHolder (rowView);
}
```

Comment: do I have to create an adapter class is that what you are telling?